# How RDD looks like from Inside?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm learning Spark.

Here is my very small code snippet for creating RDD.

```
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaRDD<String> inputFile = sparkContext.textFile(fileName);
```

In above code,`inputFile` is holding data came from file. Just curious to know how JavaRDD data structure looks like from inside to hold the data. Is it Map, List or something else ?

Am not able to find any source code for above classes, Can anyone help me for the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Apache Spark, the internal storage is managed by a component called Tungsten. It bypasses the standard Java/JVM storage you mention (maps, lists, and s on).

This blog post tells you more: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html.